# Laravel full text search with unicode character

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unicode

I have problem when search full text search.

1.First, when I search key have no unicode character, it return exact result.

```
$type = 'text';
```

`$pattern = 'okman';`

```
$nodes = Node::query()->whereRaw(" MATCH(pattern) AGAINST('$pattern') AND type = '$type' ")->get($columns);
```

The logged query

`select * from bot_nodes where  MATCH(pattern) AGAINST('okman') AND type = 'text'`

2.Then when I search key have unicode character, it return empty result.

```
$type = 'text';
$pattern = 'nghỉ đi';
$nodes = Node::query()->whereRaw(" MATCH(pattern) AGAINST('$pattern') AND type = '$type' ")->get($columns);
```

The logged query:

`select * from bot_nodes where  MATCH(pattern) AGAINST('nghỉ đi') AND type = 'text'`.

But when I copy the above query, and paste it to navicat to run, it return exact query.

I already set charset and collation is `utf8mb4` in database.php.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507087/escape-string-for-use-in-mysql-fulltext-search) or [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/214)?

Comment: Thanks. But I used the raw query like Taylorotwell said. I would like to search with unicode character in the key word. With key word doesn't have unicode character, It run okay

Comment: Works for me.  Please provide the `COLLATION` via `SHOW CREATE TABLE bot_nodes`.  Also, what version of MySQL?

Comment: And... Do you have In the file config/database.php: 'mysql' => [..., 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', ...]

Comment: And... What version of Navicat?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983996/php-mysql-site-using-utf8mb4-wont-retrieve-emojis-correctly-from-database-desp

Comment: hi @RickJames. I use Navicat version 11.0.8, MariaDB version 10.1.19 (2016). In  config/database.php, I have already set is utf8mb4.

Comment: the query when create table bot_nodes too long, I cannot show all. This is the collation when create that table:  CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: The database and table are one thing.  The "connection" is another.